# library for PDF reports

Tags: javascript, java, pdf

I am looking for a java or javascript library for PDF reports generation (think e.g. of Jasper Reports for Java). There are many frameworks so in order to select one out of these two I need some help.

Data will be coming from server using java and in UI it can be converted to report either using JS or JAVA. What I found up to know are e.g. PhantomJS and Jasper Reports.

From your experience, What Java or Javascript based library would you recommend?

Comment: @Izzy please check, is it ok now to get recommendation?

Comment: So, I'd say now it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit research I found that `JS` is not that mature for reporting and therefore I have decided to go with `JasperReports`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried IReport and JasperReports, the are basically the same thing and pretty good option to make perfect pixel reports. If you need to develop something very specific you can use iText, that is a library to plot any type of pdf (it is used inside JasperReports and is very complicated).